# What is a meaning of "p-value F" from Friedman test?

Tags: r, nonparametric

I'm a new R user and had just tried running friedman on non-normal and heteroscedastic data on seagrass.  I am testing whether biomass is significantly different between sites across years.  R (`friedman` function from `agricolae` package) returned result like this:

```
Friedman's Test
===============
Adjusted for ties
Value: 0.01333333
Pvalue chisq : 0.9080726
F value : 0.01316678
Pvalue F: 0.9086942 0.9087002

Alpha     : 0.05
t-Student : 1.990847
LSD       : 17.34995

Means with the same letter are not significantly different.
GroupTreatment and Sum of the ranks
a   1   119 
a   2   118
```

I know this means no significant difference given the p-value chisq.  But what does p-value F mean?

Comment: Can you add the name of a function/package you use?

Comment: Thanks @mbq! I have tried to figure out which one provides F-test, but no success...

Answer (score 4):

It seems the output is from the `agricolae` package using the method `friedman`.  The relevant lines for computing the two statistics in that function are:

```
T1.aj <- (m[2] - 1) * (t(s) %*% s - m[1] * C1)/(A1 - C1)
T2.aj <- (m[1] - 1) * T1.aj/(m[1] * (m[2] - 1) - T1.aj)
```

Comparing this with the formula in chl's answer, you'll notice that `T2.adj` ("F value") corresponds to $F_{obs}$ and `T1.adj` ("Value") to $F_r$.

Comment: @ars (+1) Many thanks! I missed this package... Always better to look at the code directly, I appreciate.

Comment: @chl: I was looking at the code and about to look up the formula, when I saw your answer come in. Looks like we started from different ends and met in the middle -- making a nice complement of answers. :)  (Already upvoted you.)

Comment: @ars I have to turn back to Zar's textbook because I didn't find the function though I've heard of the alternative statistic :)

Comment: sorry for the late post, but yes, i am using agricolae package.  friedman.test doesn't work on my data as it is returning an error message "your data is not an unreplicated design" to that effect.       but why are there 2 p-value f's?  am i right that the first is for the the treatment and the second for the block?

Comment: @kathy: see chl's answer for an explanation of what the two mean -- the first value you see is $F_r$ and the "value f" is $F_{obs}$ in his answer.  Also, it's possible you're passing the arguments in the wrong order to the friedman.test method; it should be (data, group, block).

Comment: aw, thanks ars, now i get it, its the adjusted value...mmmm that's why i'm wondering why its so close to the chisqr value

Answer (score 3):

I generally used `friedman.test()` which doesn't return any F statistic. If you consider that you have $b$ blocks, for which you assigned ranks to observations belonging to each of them, and that you sum these ranks for each of your $a$ groups (let denote them sum $R_i$), then the Friedman statistic is defined as

$$
F_r=\frac{12}{ba(a+1)}\sum_{i=1}^aR_i^2-3b(a+1)
$$

and follows a $\chi^2(a-1)$, for $a$ and $b$ sufficiently large. Quoting Zar (*Biostatistical Analysis*, 4th ed., pp. 263-264), this approximation is conservative (hence, test has low power) and we can use an F-test, with

$$
F_{\text{obs}}=\frac{(b-1)F_r}{b(a-1)-F_r}
$$

which is to be compared to an F distribution with $a-1$ and $(a-1)(b-1$) degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Probably $p_F$ refers to the F-statistic developed by Iman and Davenport? They showed that Friedman’s $\chi^2$ is undesirably conservative and derived a "better" statistic

$F_F=\frac{(N-1)\chi^2_F}{N(k-1)-\chi^2_F}$

which is distributed according to the F-distributionwith k−1 and (k−1)(N−1) degrees of freedom.

**References:**

Demsar, J. (2006). Statistical Comparisons of Classifiers over Multiple Data Sets. Journal of Machine Learning Research, 7, p. 11.

Iman, R. L.  and Davenport,J. M. Approximations of the critical region of the Friedman statistic. Communications in Statistics, pages 571–595, 1980.